# Error while installing visual studio 2017 ms c++ 2017 x86 Minimum Runtime

Tags: visual-studio

I have this this error while installing the Visual Studio 2017
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDlRJ.jpg]

It's failed then.
How to fix this problem ?

Comment: You are not given right path to load